# Is ALL CAPS hard to read?

Tags: reading

A 2009 regulation in the US specifies that street name signs "shall be composed of a combination of lower-case letters with initial upper-case letters" ([source](http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/htm/2009/part2/part2d.htm#section2D43)).  For example, "[DOLLYWOOD](http://www.usatoday.com/news/nation/2010-10-21-road-signs-all-caps-lowercase_N.htm)" would not be okay, but should instead be "Dollywood".

I suppose the argument is that lowercase is easier to read, while all-caps is easier to notice.  Although my common sense doesn't disagree, are there any studies backing this up?

Comment: Lowercase letters differ in size, but CAPS DO NOT. Therefore there is a greater variation, making it easier to read. Since I don't have a source at hand, to back this up, <strike> I give you advice: JUST BELIEVE ME </strike> I post this as a comment.

Comment: IMO a wall of CAPS is **very** annoying to read, normal wall of text is marginally better, paragraphed CAPS is still annoying, and normal paragraphed text is best

Comment: EXACTLY! IT FEELS AS IF THE PERSON WRITING IT WAS CONSTANTLY YELLING AT YOU!!!111!!

Comment: Many legal agreements have section headings that are written entirely in upper-case letters, which seems to make it easier to find each section (particularly when they're also in **bold**).  Seeing an entire paragraph written in upper-case can be slightly more tiring to read though.

Comment: @Randolf Richardson: Indeed.  A good example is the NO WARRANTY section of many software licenses.  The purpose is [to be conspicuous](http://www.mslater.com/post/104847-why-are-warranty-disclaimers-in-all), but I tend to ignore paragraphs containing all-caps text.  It'd be better if "NO WARRANTY" was a header, followed by mixed-case text.

Comment: I dont think that all caps is hard to read it is just that mixed is easier to comprehend quickly.  That said I Do not know that this was the cause of enough problems with traffic to warrent the feds getting their overpaid fatassed noses involved.

Comment: @Chad:  "Warrant" isn't the first word that comes to mind for me.  (_Why does my sudden coughing sound a little bit like the phrase "kick-back scheme?"_)  ;-D

Comment: The cynical side of me suspects that the NO WARRANTY section is put in all caps partly *because* it's harder to read.

Comment: It's common to say that mixed case text is easier to read because we can see the shapes of words at a glance, but I'm pretty sure there's a study demonstrating that this is not so: mixed case is *actually* easier because we're more used to it. But I have no idea where I read that, which is why this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: There is a study by Kevin Larson (Microsoft) regarding this where it is *not* related to traffic signs, which seems to be the area most concerned about this particular subject. Anyway, here's the link: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ctfonts/WordRecognition.aspx

Comment: ALL CAPS letters are bigger, thus requiring more eye movement, more effort to read. Plus we are customed to the small caps image of words, it also makes them harder to recognize.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mostly yes, but it depends. For fixed-message road signs, mixed-case outperforms upper-case, according to [Garvey et al. (1997), Effects of font and capitalization on legibility of guide signs. Transportation Research Record 1605:73](http://trid.trb.org/view.aspx?id=475144). In their introduction, they state that

> Forbes et al. (2) conducted what are perhaps the definitive studies of
>   the difference in legibility between text depicted in all uppercase letters
>   and that depicted in lowercase with initial capital letters. When
>   upper- and mixed-case words occupied the same sign area, Forbes and
>   his colleagues found a significant improvement in reading distance
>   with the mixed-case words. It must be understood, however, that these
>   results were obtained with a recognition task. That is, the observers
>   knew what words they were looking for. In instances in which the text
>   is not known to the observer, improvements with mixed-case words
>   are not evident (1,2). Although mixed-case superiority is fairly well
>   accepted in the traffic engineering community [Markowitz et al. (4)
>   provided specific information suggesting the use of mixed-case lettering
>   for conventional road guide signs in 1968], conventional road
>   guide signs still are being created with all uppercase letters.

Assuming that the authors can summarize prior research, I didn't hunt down the Forbes reference; here's the info for those who want to look at the original source:
*Forbes, T. W., K. Moscowitz, and G. Morgan. A Comparison of Lower
Case and Capital Letters for Highway Signs. Proc., 30th Annual Meeting
of the Highway Research Board, Washington, D.C., 1950.*

After testing their new font, "Clearview" (which is, to me, indeed easy to read), Garvey et al. find again that

> The mixed-case Clearview characters outperformed the all-uppercase
>   Series D by as much as 14 percent in daytime and 16 percent at night,
>   as long as the mixed-case font subtended an equivalent sign area. If
>   the mixed-case font took up less sign space, as with the Clearview
>   Condensed at 100 percent, there was no difference between mixedcase
>   and all-uppercase characters. During daytime testing there was
>   no difference between Series E(M) and any comparably sized
>   Clearview font (i.e., Clearview and Clearview at 112 percent). At
>   night, however, with both high-brightness materials, the Clearview
>   font at 112 percent outperformed the Series E(M) by 16 percent.

Note that things are different for the variable-message road signs (i.e. the ones you may see at road construction sites. There, all uppercase is better, according to [Collins and Hall, (1992). Legibility and readability of light refecting matrix variable message road signs, Lighting Research and Technology 24:143](http://lrt.sagepub.com/content/24/3/143.short).

> In general, letters with any regular shaped pixel, a width/height ratio approaching 1.0, an upper case font and a letter separation of two pixels were found to be most effective.